# Convert single HTML Page to an APP

Tags: android, cordova

Hi have a Single HTML page that i would like to convert to an Android App.
This page has resources such as JQuery, Javascript, audio, video and image files that are inside a sub folder.
What's the best way and steps to convert it to a simple APP?

Comment: Unless you embed your website into a WebView in the app, I think you will need to basically write a new app using your audio/image/video files. AFAIK, there arent any tools to just "convert" your site into an APP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Get any good IDE, I will suggest `Eclipse IDE`.
2. Install `PhoneGap Plugin` for development in PhoneGap easily.
3. `` `Create New `` PhoneGap project.
4. Replace the `assests/www` folder with `your project's www folder`.
5. Emulate on `AVD` or Do `USB Debugging`.

NOTE: PhoneGap has limited APIs to use right now. In PhoneGap 3.0, we are expecting much more functionalities. Although, you can definitely create your own plugins required for your project.

You can get common plugins [here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins).

Also, there are some basic steps to be followed to integrate your existing project to PhoneGap.

Comment: My project doesn't involve any specific features that require API. It is just basicaly HTML with JS/JQuery animations. 
Do you know any tutorial to integrate an existing project to PhoneGap?
Googled, but couldn't find nothing just for that.

Answer (score 4):

Check out Phonegap. It claims to be able to accomplish something like this.

http://phonegap.com/

Comment: Yes PhoneGap will help you. It will pack your HTML/CSS/JS code and give you apk file for Android. If you wanna use Camera etc. PhoneGap has API for this, check it out, nice library.